# Delete a Post without the associated Task

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I would like to be able to destroy my Post without the Task which is associated. But I'm currently facing a SQL error which say:

```
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey (SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed: DELETE FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ?):
```

After a few search, I saw that is coming from associations and Foreign Key. But I cannot solve the problem for the moment.

I have tested to put (optional: true) into my model.

I also have tried to change the foreign key into (, on_delete: :cascade) & (, on_delete: :nullify) but it's still not working.

My code =

```
//Post Model
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :task
end

//Task Model
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post, optional: true
end
```

To destroy :

```
//Destroy_one into the Post Controller
def destoy_one
  @post.destroy
end
```

Migration File : (also tried with on_delete: :nullify)

```
class EditForeightKeys < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    # remove the old foreign_key
    remove_foreign_key :tasks, :post

    # add the new foreign_key
    add_foreign_key :tasks, :post, on_delete: :cascade

  end
end
```

Do you have any other solution for that ?

Comment: did u tried @post.delete   ?

Comment: Hi @krishnar, happy to see you again ! Yep absolutely

Comment: just remove `on_delete` parameter from migration

Comment: Well I have precisely made this migration to solve the problem

Comment: @stigGaret  add_foreign_key :tasks, :post, on_delete: :nullify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this issue by implement a deleted_state into Posts

```
def destroy_one
  @post.update(deleted_state: true)
end
```

And after you can put a default scope into your Post model like this :

```
default_scope { where(deleted_state: false) }
```

Like this all will work without problems !!

Comment: Thanks for this solution @jacquesMesnet, It's an elegant solution to solve it !

Answer (score 0):

You can use callbacks on destroy action for `User` as a variant:

```
class Post
    before_destroy :update_tasks

    private

    def update_tasks
        self.tasks.update_all(post_id: nil)
    end
end
```